# How to colour folders controlled by SVN in terminal?

Tags: svn, shell, terminal

Is there a way to get the SVN controlled folders list with different colors in the terminal? Like an alias for "ls". So when we type "ls", all the folders with an ".svn" sub-folder should be yellow for example?

Thanks.
(Sorry if that is a stupid question.)

Comment: this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/using-dircolors-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-subversion-folders) seem like what you wanted.

Comment: @Jasonw: Not quite. That link talks about the `.svn` directory only, not which are part of a SVN repo.

Comment: This is duplicate question. Please have a look this link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667887/colorize-filename-according-to-svn-status

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a wrapper around `ls` to do this.

I wrote such a wrapper below...

How it basically works:

- `ls -F` is forced because directories are then guaranteed to have a `/` suffix that can be detected.
- To resolve a directory's name to its location, either the current directory is used or the first non-dash argument (presumed to be a target directory).
- The foreground/background colors are achieved using the first number sets of each line.  The XTerm-style numbers are triplets, so the 3rd and 6th numbers are the colors (19 and 85 in my example).  The colors can of course be changed to anything you want.
- This relies on original versions of `svn` where `.svn` was present in every subdirectory.  If you're using the latest version where `.svn` is only present at the top, the script should change to "drill upward" from a "$root/$dir" until it finds a parent directory containing `.svn`.

Here is my entire script (use instead of `ls` directly):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# by Kevin Grant (kevingrant.engineer@gmail.com)
use FileHandle;
my $term = (exists $ENV{'TERM'} && defined $ENV{'TERM'}) ? $ENV{'TERM'} : 'vt100';
my $is_xterm = ($term =~ /xterm/);
my $ifh = new FileHandle("ls -F @ARGV|");
(defined $ifh) or die;
my $root = '.';
foreach (@ARGV) {
  (! /^\-/) and $root = $_; # assume bare argument is the directory being listed
}
foreach (<$ifh>) {
  # 1st is for "ls -l" output (no spaces supported), 2nd is normal "ls" output
  if (m|\s(\S+)/| or m|^([^/]+/)|) {
    my $dir = $1;
    if (-e "$root/$dir/.svn") {
      # has a ".svn" subdirectory; colorize it
      if ($is_xterm) {
        s/\Q${dir}\E/\033[48;5;19;38;5;85m${dir}\033[0m/;
      } else {
        s/\Q${dir}\E/\033[44;36m${dir}\033[0m/;
      }
    }
  }
  print;
}
```